# Angular - Logout redirect route

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a route that clears the users session and redirects them back to the root homepage.

```
.config(function config( $routeProvider, $stateProvider ) {

    $routeProvider.
        when('/logout', {resolve: {redirect: function(Session){
            Session.clear();
            return "/home";
        }}});
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, as calling

```
$location.path("/logout");
```

... ignores the function and redirects back to the default route. I've tried adding console.log statements to the function to see if it is being called.

Am I using the redirect function incorrectly?

Comment: Try : when('/', {resolve: {redirect: function($state){
            $state.go("/home");
        }}}   ---

Comment: or even: when('/', {resolve: {redirect: function(){
            redirectTo : '/home'
        }}}

Answer (score 19):

Have you considered putting your logout logic in a separate controller? Would be a little cleaner, more robust, & make redirection more straightforward. Like so:

```
function LogoutController($location) {
    Session.clear();
    $location.path('/home');
}
```

The your route is:

```
when('/logout', {
  template: '', //A template or templateUrl is required by AngularJS, even if your controller always redirects.
  controller: 'LogoutController'
}).
```

Comment: I was under the impression routes always needed a template for controllers to work?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Should be easy to test, and worst case you can use a dummy template.

Comment: routes do need a template, but you can simply set it to be empty with template: ' ' when configuring the route

Comment: Is it possible to set loader instead of empty template? In my case logout is a bit long and empty page is not a good solution. We use dummy login page, but it is not also really cool when visually login page does not respond and redirects to login after a couple of sec.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and what I did instead was create a logout function in my navigationController that gets hit when the URL is clicked

```
 <li><a href="" ng-click="logout()" target="_self">Log Out</a></li>
```

And in my navigationController:

```
$scope.logout = function () {
                localStorage.clearAll();
                window.location = '/logout';
            };
```

I'm running ASP.NET behind Angular so I needed the browser (not angular) to route to /logout which is mapped in ASP.NET config (does a few other session clean ups and redirects to authentication app)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

just store the $sessionStorage (username) then delete the the $sessionStorage (username) ..

```
         $scope.logout = function(){
         delete $sessionStorage.sessname; //sessname is get sessionStorage username 
           $location.path('/login');
                     };
```

help me for this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056745/angularjs-click-logout-button-to-clear-sessionstorage-again-and-again-go-back-to

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/logout', {
            resolve: {
                logout: ['authService', function (authService) {
                    authService.clear(true);
                }]
            }
        })
```