# AngularJS logout not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried logout my current session. But logout not working. Check below my code:

**view**

```
<a ui-sref="logout">
   <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
</a>
```

**config.js**

```
$stateProvider
            .state('logout', {
                url: "/logout",
                templateUrl: '',
                controller: "LogoutController"
            });
```

**controllers.js**

```
function LogoutController($location, $http) {
    alert("hi");
    //Session.clear();
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "users/ajaxLogout",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
    request.success(function(data) {

    });
    $location.path('/login');
}

angular
   .module('inspinia')
   .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
   .controller('LogoutController', LogoutController);
```

I have alerted in `LogoutController` but that function not calling while I am clicking `Log out` link.

I follow this link - [Angular - Logout redirect route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635407/angular-logout-redirect-route#answer-19640276) Please check and let me know where is error in my code.

Comment: See **[mcve]**. Explain exactly what is not working.

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Are there any errors in console?

Comment: No console error found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the logout code inside a function in your controller:

```
function LogoutController($location, $http, $scope) {

    this.logout = function() {
        alert("hi");
        //Session.clear();
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "users/ajaxLogout",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
        request.success(function(data) {
            $location.path('/login');
        });

    }
}
```

And then call the function on clicking the logout link by using ng-click:

```
<div ng-controller="LogoutController as ctrl">
<a ui-sref="logout">
   <i class="fa fa-sign-out" ng-click="ctrl.logout()"></i> Log out
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working. But I am getting another error. After login page automatically logout without click the logout link. :(

Comment: I am not sure if $stateProvider is needed for logout functionality. So see if it's causing errors. Also, please see updated code. I've put the $location.path('/login'); under "request.sucess()" function.

Answer (score -1):

check in console that are your getting an error and try

```
  angular .controller('LogoutController', function($scope,$state,$location,$ionicHistory, $http) {
    console.log("hello");
     $state.go('app.login');
     $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    };
```